# Mongoose ask for documents not referenced by another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection structures using MongoDB and Mongoose:

```
const UserSchema = 
{
  "name": {
    "type": "String",
    "required": true,
    "unique": true
  },
  "company_id": {
    "type": "ObjectId"
    "ref": "Company"
    "required": true
   }

const CompanySchema = 
{
  "name": {
    "type": "String",
    "required": true,
    "unique": true
  },
  "ein": {
    "type": "String"
  }
}
```

What is the fastest way to get all companies that are not referenced by any user (all companies that have no users)?

My first tought is:

```
User.find({}).exec()
.then(users => {
    Company.find({ id: { $in: users}}).exec()
})
.then(companiesWithoutRefs => {
    return companiesWithoutRefs;
})
.catch(err => {
   throw new err;
});
```

Questions:

1. Are the promises structured correctly?
2. Do I need to convert the $in: users statement to ObjectId? How to do so with multiple values?

And the last and most important one:

3. Is there a way to do this query without fully loading the User collection, something smarter?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better way would be to use the [aggregation framework](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) and apply the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline stage to do a lookup on the related data which you can then query by checking to see if any element exists in the returned array:

```
Company.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "company_id",
            "as": "company_users"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "company_users.0": { "$exists": false } } }
]).exec().then(res.json)
```

Comment: That kinf of thing is what I was looking for. Aggretation is new to me, so thanks for the info.

Comment: please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208410/graphql-error-returning-result-of-mongoose-aggregate-command) as a continuation of that... You may be of help there also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have improved your query

```
User.find({}).exec()
.then(users => {
    let companyIds = users.map(o => o.company_id);
    return Company.find({ id: { $nin: companyIds}}).exec()
})
.then(companiesWithoutRefs => {
    return companiesWithoutRefs;
})
.catch(err => {
   throw new err;
});
```

1. Your structure is correct but your query is not.
2. because of your schema design you have to fire two queries. For one query you can use concept of subdocument