# GraphQL error returning result of mongoose aggregate command

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, graphql, graphql-js

This question is related to [the answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48207222/2697571)

I need to return an aggregation result from a GraphQL query. Here is the query code:

```
const companiesWithNoUsers = {
    type: new GraphQLList(CompanyType),
    resolve(root, args, context) {
        return Company.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    localField: "id",
                    foreignField: "company_id",
                    as: "company_users"
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "company_users:0": {
                        $exists: false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
    }
};
```

I´m getting the follwing error at GraphQL:

```
Expected value of type \"Company\" but got: [object Object].
```

After reading [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate), I imagine the error is related to the following statement:

*"The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned)."*

So, I need to return a GraphQL `CompanyType`. How do I cast the return to the format expected to GraphQL ? Is there another solution for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the results list to Mongoose documents and wrap the result in a Promise as:

```
Company.aggregate(pipeline).exec((err, result) => 
    (    
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {                    
                resolve(result.map(doc => { 
                    delete doc.company_users;
                    return new Company( doc );
                }))
            }
        })
    ))
```

Comment: Not working. `TypeError: _types.Company is not a constructor`... Problems when casting object to GraphQLType `Company`...

Comment: The above `Company` is a Mongoose document

Comment: Yes, I found out. But still not working. Same error: `"Expected value of type \"User\" but got: [object Object]."`. I´ve checked the output and it is an array of Company mongoose document. No idea what is still missing... In fact calling `let company = new company(doc); console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(company))` I get printed `[object Object]`....